# Mysql REPLACE resulted in 0 values on all rows

Tags: mysql, replace

I've used the following SQL query in a MySQL database to replace part of a string in a cell:

```
UPDATE TEST.database2014 SET together1 = REPLACE(together1, "/1900", "20")
```

For some reason all the rows (225,000!) have now a value of 0.

This is the message which I got:

> /* Affected rows:225,000  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 16,888 sec. */

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
data example contained in field together1:

```
TESTING^^^19/01/2014^^
```

Is there a known reason for this happening?
I find it strange that if no matches where found it converted all values to 0 anyway.

Comment: I think `Found rows` only counts rows returned by a `SELECT`.

Comment: I don't see any way that that query could have that effect.

Comment: what's the type of together1?

Comment: @almasshaikh, the type is VARCHAR(255)

Comment: What is table definition, basically I am interested in datatype of together1. Would be more helpfull if you add some data sample from table stored in together1.

Comment: your column togheter1 contains /1900 ? Or it contains 1900 ...

Comment: Î have ammended my original post to show an example of data found in field together1.  @Mailkov, field contains /1900, including the /

Comment: but if you use this  SELECT * TEST.database2014 WHERE togheter1 LIKE '%/1900' how many rows found?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must use this:

```
UPDATE TEST.database2014 SET together1 = REPLACE(together1, "/19", "/20") WHERE togheter1 LIKE '%/19%'
```

if you want to upate all year 1900 to 2000

Comment: What I typed was just an example, in fact I want to change (for example) 19/01/1900 to 20 (was originally a date, now needs to be changed to a number). The thing is I did what you mention, however it converted ALL records to 0 value...So I am asuming there is something strange happening...

Comment: you can prove this: UPDATE TEST.database2014 SET together1 = REPLACE(together1, "/19", "/20") WHERE togheter1 LIKE '%/19%'

Comment: excuse me but you want that all date with year 1900 change in simple 20?

Comment: you can insert an example with first value and changed value that you want ?

Comment: by mistake, several numbers where entered as a date (due to conversion from number to date format) ont he template we use to input data into mysql. So where it should be a 20, it's now a date, this is the reason why I need to change all those dates to numbers.

Comment: The thing is that the problem has already been solved (I manually changed it...) but I was trying to find out if this "problem" has occured to other people before and needed some feedback on how to avoid it in future....