# Update statement with Replace function results zero "0" value for all rows

Tags: mysql, replace, sql-update

I ran the following statement in our test mysql database, it works properly. However, when I ran it in production, I got all rows, including those of CLASS = 'ClassName', updated with XML value set to 0 !

```
 UPDATE table_name c set c.XML= REPLACE (c.XML, '<flag_name>false</flag_name>', '')
WHERE c.CLASS = 'ClassName'
```

I want to know the reason behind this strange behaviour?

Note: The table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CLASS` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `XML` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23510 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The expected behaviour is to remove the targeted tag

Comment: I found following case but the column is of date type! This was not the case here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417833/mysql-replace-resulted-in-0-values-on-all-rows

Comment: In that other question, the column is `VARCHAR` type, not `DATE`.

Comment: you are right.. it is VARCHAR .. though, I don't get the reason so far!

Comment: In that other question, he needed to do the replacement because some other software had mistakenly formatted the value as if it were a date, and he needed to undo that. It has nothing to do with why he got `0` as a result. There's no accepted answer there, so it's not really relevant.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7nvJbY24rmp6BKegdYzxwa/0